With a Source Generator, how to generate source using an aggregate of all transformed nodes?
Using a Source Generator, I want to generate a single file that is built using an aggregate list of all the transformed nodes (instead of one at a time).
I'll use an Enum-based example as these are common. Given (simplified for clarity):
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            IncrementalValuesProvider<MyEnumData?> sources = context.SyntaxProvider
                .ForAttributeWithMetadataName(
                    MyEnumAttributeFullName,
                    predicate: (node, _) => node is EnumDeclarationSyntax,
                    transform: MyTransform)
                .WithTrackingName("Gathering")
                .Where(static node => node is not null)
                .WithTrackingName("RemovingNulls");

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(sources, static (context, sources) => Execute(context, in sources));
        }

In this example, Execute is used to generate a source file based on the transformed MyEnumData for every enum tagged with MyEnumAttributeFullName.
My question: How do I generate/register a source file to be created bases on ALL of the generated MyEnumData (instead of one at a time)? I'm looking for an efficient compile-time solution that does not involve runtime reflection.
Basically I'm looking for the equivalent of:
public void RegisterSourceOutput<TSource>(IncrementalValuesProvider<TSource> source, Action<SourceProductionContext, ARRAY_OR_LIST_OF_ALL_TSOURCES> action) 

Used to create to generate a single file that is built using an aggregated list of all the transformed nodes.
This could be used compose compile-time registries that avoid runtime reflection. In this enums example, this might be used to create a registry of all enums tagged with MyEnumAttributeFullName.
My first thought was to manually create/populate this somehow:
    IncrementalValuesProvider<List<MyEnumData>?> = ???

...and register a handler to process that single node. But I could not figure out how to perform the population step. It seems like  it would be a common usage pattern, but I couldn't find anything.
EDIT: While this question was answered, it occurred to me that if you are generating sources across multiple projects and wanting to create a source generated registry in you main app, these probably need to be two separate generators that (by-definition) cannot depend on each other's output.

Are you looking for Collect and Combine? https://github.com/DapperLib/DapperAOT/blob/main/src/Dapper.AOT.Analyzers/CodeAnalysis/DapperInterceptorGenerator.cs#L33

@MarcGravell Yes, I believe Collect is what I'm looking for. Your link provides for interesting reading as well. Thanks.
